# Как получить список всех залогиненых пользователей в Django?

Tags: django

Приветы.
Есть проект, в котором не хотелось бы разрешать пользователям открывать новые вкладки в других браузерах и повторно авторизоваться на ресурсе. Т.е.  залогинен пользователь должен быть только с одной вкладки. Можно ли как то получить всех залогиненых пользователей в Django на текущий момент времени ? Для того чтобы сделать примерно следующее:

```
all_login_users = Получить список залогиненых пользователей на текущий момент.
If user in all_login_users: # Если пользователь есть в списке   
     user.logout() # выходим из всех вкладок в которых мы залогинились раньше   
     user.login() # логинимся по новой.
```

Может быть есть какие то другие механизмы для данной реализации ? Требуется соблюсти атомарность действий пользователя.

Comment: Это не про сессии?

https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/http/sessions.html

Кстати, а зачем проверять?
Может проще просто пытаться делать logout в любом случае?
А потом вход. Без проверок.